json_path filter not working on Object, works on Array
I am using the Dart library json_path to filter JSON objects.
When I try to filter objects based on a field value, the filter works if the object values are stored inside an array, while it does not if it is a regular field of the parent object, see the example. I tried several syntax variations. All work on the array but not on the single object, what am I missing?
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:json_path/json_path.dart';

void main() {
  // This example works, note the inner array with just one element
  final docArray = jsonDecode('''
{
  "store": {
     "auto":    
     [  
      {
      "price": 10
    }  
    ]
  }
}    ''');

  // This example does not work, single field instead of array
  final docObject = jsonDecode('''
{
  "store": {
     "auto":     
      {
      "price": 10
    }  
  }
}    ''');
  print('\nauto   Object :');
  JsonPath(r'$.store.auto[?@.price < 20]').readValues(docObject).forEach(print);

  print('auto   Array:');
  JsonPath(r'$.store.auto[?@.price < 20]').readValues(docArray).forEach(print);
}

Output:
auto   object :
auto   Array:
{price: 10}
Process finished with exit code 0

I'm not sure that I understand what you expect to get back from that first JSON path query, as you're already selecting the auto property. If you want all properties of store with a price < 20, that'd be JsonPath(r'$.store[?@.price < 20]').

With the $.store.auto in your expression, you already point to one property in store (auto). So that's a single node, meaning that there is no array to filter on (and a filter expression always returns an array).
If you want to get a list of the properties that have a price < 20, you can do:
JsonPath(r'$.store[?@.price < 20]')

It's a bit easier to see in this screenshot: 
I added a second property in the store object, and added a name attribute to them to make it easier to see what nodes are being selected.
My test bed on Zapp.run: https://zapp.run/edit/jsonpath-testing-zs9u06qxs9v0

Pedantically, a filter expression (or any selector) returns a list of nodes, each of which carries value and location information.  It's not the same as a JSON Array.

The $.store.auto[?@.price < 20] is a filter expression indeed, so it returns a list, but the $.store.auto isn't (afaik), which is why filtering doesn't return anything there. I tried to clarify a bit in my answer, but not sure if it helped. If that is (still) not correct or how you'd explain it, please suggest an edit or post an alternative answer with how to better accomplish the use-case.
